# What App is used to create the following diagram

Tags: diagram, uml, er-diagram

I am reading this repository in GitHub.

https://github.com/donnemartin/system-design-primer.

I liked the design of the diagram used in that repo, Please tell me which  tool is used to create this diagram.

Please let me know if there are any other tool similar to this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We don't do "software identification" here. As I assume you'd also be happy with recommendations of what software could be used to create similar diagrams, would you please [edit] your question and provide the missing details: what OS should it run on? What's your price limit if it comes to paid software?

Comment: Why not open an issue on the project and ask?